SwiftUI : How to set the height of an empty Text to one line
I have a Text that is initially empty and is populated with custom text by pressing buttons. The size of the font is
.dynamicTypeSize(.xxxLarge)
I want to display the Text within a fixed frame surrounded by a border. The problem is when the Text is empty, the frame flattens.
Here is the code of the textview:
                                Text(filtreString)
                                    .padding(6)
                                    .dynamicTypeSize(.xxxLarge)
                                    .frame( maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .background(Color("fondbleu"))
                                    .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                                    .cornerRadius(20.0)
                                    .overlay(
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20).stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1))

Here is the textview, empty and populated:

It might be quite simple, but I could not find the way to set the height of the view without populating some text inside the textview. I could for example put a space character " " but I would like to avoid that because the empty string is one of the possible values.
Can someone help me out ? Thanks !
I tried something like font.lineHeight but the compiler did not seem to like it.

I was going to suggest reserving space for a line limit:
Text(filtreString)
    .lineLimit(1, reservesSpace: true)

However, it seems this doesn't help either (maybe a bug).
So I would suggest showing a space instead of an empty string:
Text(filtreString.isEmpty ? " " : filtreString)

Alternatively, you could use a hidden placeholder to reserve the height, then show the text as an overlay:
Text(".")
    .hidden()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .overlay { Text(filtreString) }
    .dynamicTypeSize(.xxxLarge)
    .padding(6)
    .background {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
            .fill(Color("fondbleu"))
            .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1)
    }


I like #2 solution: keeps it simple and preserves the empty string value. Thanks Benzy.

Looks like you really should be reaching for a TextField, not a Text. Even better would be to make your overall view .searchable, if your navigation structure allows it.
If you really need a Text for some reason, you could specify a minHeight in your .frame modifier.

Hal, I am using a Text because I use my own custom keyboard. I don't want the standard keyboard to pop up and don't need the focus in the text. Regarding the .frame modifier, you are right. The only question is what to specify as minHeight. I still don't know the answer.

That's a complicated question. You need to respect the text height of the default font, which might be larger or smaller than you specified if the user has used dynamic type to change the default font size. You COULD get the info by using a GeometryReader, but that brings a brand new set of complications. Since you're customizing the keyboard and appearance, I think you'll be better off using @benzyknees's alternate approach using an .overlay, which to my eye (and without testing) respects dynamic type.
